# Wpf listview combobox binding DisplayMemberPath not working

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, combobox

I have the following code in Wpf form:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class ProductWithValue
{
    public Product Object_Product { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ListProduct { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ProductWithValue> ListProdValue { get; set; }
}

Data data = LoadData();

lstProducts.DataContext = data;
```

The XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lstProducts" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListProdValue}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="23">
                <ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.ListProduct}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Object_Product, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

LoadData example:

```
private Data LoadData()
{
    Data data = new Data();

    Product prod1 = new Product(){Name="Name1", Type = "Type1"};
    Product prod2 = new Product(){Name="Name2", Type = "Type2"};

    data.ListProduct = new ObservableCollection<Product>()
    {
        prod1,
        prod2
    };

    data.ListProdValue = new ObservableCollection<ProductWithValue>()
    {
         new ProductWithValue(){ Object_Product = prod1, Value="Value"  }
    };

    return data;
}
```

Evrything is fine, except the DisplayMemberPath.
The combobox itemssource is correct, the selected item is correct, but does not show the Name of the Product.

Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: XAML code looks ok, could you add to question code to `LoadData` method?

Comment: what do you see instead ? any object path or blank ?

Comment: I see just a blank field.

Comment: The LoadData just fills the lists with data, evrything ok with that.

Comment: @KishonthyMárton take a screenshot of your view and add to question.

Comment: Just blank comboboxes in a listview.

Comment: @KishonthyMárton your code is working ok, can you create complete project with your problem and add it to question?

Comment: I made a mistake when write here the question, I correct my code during write the question. The above code is ok. In my projekt, I create a new object when fill the ListProdValue: data.ListProdValue = new ObservableCollection<ProductWithValue>()
    {
         new ProductWithValue(){ Object_Product = new Product("p1","t1"), Value="Value"  }
    };  And the values are the same, but I think the reference is not from ListProduct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong LoadData function in my code:

```
private Data LoadData()
{
    Data data = new Data();

    Product prod1 = new Product() { Name = "Name1", Type = "Type1" };
    Product prod2 = new Product() { Name = "Name2", Type = "Type2" };
    Product prod3 = new Product() { Name = "Name3", Type = "Type3" };

    data.ListProduct = new ObservableCollection<Product>()
    {
        prod1,
        prod2,
        prod3
    };

    data.ListProdValue = new ObservableCollection<ProductWithValue>()
    {
        new ProductWithValue(){ Object_Product = new Product() { Name = "Name1", Type = "Type1" }, Value="Value1"  },
        new ProductWithValue(){ Object_Product = new Product() { Name = "Name2", Type = "Type2" }, Value="Value2"  }
    };

    return data;
}
```